# How to unsubscribe react-native-firebase getInitialNotification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using `react-native-firebase` for push notifications in a `react-native` application.

When a notification is received, opens the app by clicking on the notification (this works correctly by triggering the `getInitialNotification` function). However, when i navigate from one screen to another it will be triggered again. How can this be stopped? is there any alternative to unsubscribe this event after it is triggered?
Or is there any workaround to this issue?

```
class Header extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPermission();
    this.createNotificationListeners();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationListener();
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
  }

  async checkPermission() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        this.getToken();
    }
  }

  async getToken() {
   //token retrieve code
  }

  async createNotificationListeners() {

    firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic("all")

    /*
    * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
    * */
    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
        alert(title, body);

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View></View>
    );
  }
}
```